# MariaDB master-bin Log Rotation

Tags: mariadb, master-slave-replication, log

I've just setup MariaDB replication with 2 slaves in *Debian 11 (Bullseye)*.  I'm a bit alarmed to see the file size reach such a size without log rotation:

```
-rw-rw----  1 mysql adm  297394983 Dec  8 05:55 master-bin.000001
-rw-rw----  1 mysql adm         33 Dec  5 19:32 master-bin.index
```

In the steps to setup replication I modified the **master** *MariaDB* /etc/mysql/my.cnf file **[mariadb]** section

```
[mariadb]
log-bin
server_id=1
log-basename=master1
binlog-format=mixed
```

It isn't clear to me how to setup log rotation for this in a way that isn't going to break the 2 slaves.  I am wondering if it is possible to setup master-bin.000001 to rotate once a day and delete old ones after 28 days.

I have searched the web.  I am seeing comments about slave log rotation online.  It isn't "clicking" how to do this for this master files.

Answer (score 2):

What is the value of `max_binlog_size`?  Older versions of MySQL/MariaDB default it to 1G, which you have not yet hit.  Newer versions rotate at 100M.   Either value works equally well (unless you are extremely tight on disk space).

Each replica is taking care of itself; don't worry about rotations.

After it passes the specified size, rotation occurs.  The Both Replicas will be informed by the Primary.

See `binlog_expire_logs_seconds` or `expire_logs_days` for how to cause 'old' logs to be deleted automatically.

`sync_binlog` is another one to check.  Set it to 1.

Be aware the logs on different servers in a replication setup will rotate independently.